# accessing web.xml params inside a contextInitializer class

Tags: spring, profile

so several articles describe how to configure spring.profiles.active inside a contextInitializerClass. You'd add something like the below to web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mycompany.SpringProfileInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And the corresponding class:

```
public class SpringProfileInitializer implements       ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        environment.setActiveProfiles( getActiveProfiles(NEED_PARAM_HERE) );            
    }

}
```

But i need to get an argument into the call to getActiveProfiles() above; just a string will do, as long as it's "somewhere" in the web.xml file.

How can i do this?

Thx.

EDIT: Just to back up a step, the problem i'm *really* trying to solve is the notion of multiple wars running in one JVM, each wanting a different spring.profiles.active property, AND, the value of spring.profiles.active is going to be env-specific, sitting inside some property file.

Clearly, i can't use **-Dspring.active.profiles**, since this is global to the JVM. We already have a per-war properties file that is env-specific, each war knows how to pull this prop file in by using a **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**. Adding the **spring.profiles.active** property to this prop file doesn't work (presumably it's too late in the process). Note that these war-specific prop files are all installed in some known location on disk, with some war-specific name.

Now, i can solve my problem in 2 ways using **ApplicationContextInitializer** as described above.

1) I can simply have a new class per war that implements **ApplicationContextInitializer**, likely extending some "base" class that does the real work. The class-per-war will simply hardcode the name of the prop file, read it in, and pull out the spring.profiles.active property.

2) I can create a war-specific prop file with the same name across wars, call it **spring-profile-loc.properties**. This file will contain just one property, the name of the aforementioned war-specific prop file. In this scenario, there is just the **SpringProfileInitializer** class i have above, and it just reads in this **spring-profile-loc.properties** file, pulls out the single prop, and then reads in the real prop file to access the **spring.profiles.active** prop (there are other variants of this idea as well).

I'm not fond of either approach, they seem clunky and roundabout. It would be simpler if i can just "configure" something in the web.xml and access it directly in my impl of **ApplicationContextInitializer**.

But if there's some completely different approach to solving this, i'm all ears.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to implement ServletContextAware and then use servletContext.getInitParameter() (or getAttribute() ?)

but i don't know if getting servletContext injected at this point works

Comment: Nope, the servletContext is never injected into SpringProfileInitializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate profiles by this in the web.xml file:

In your Dispatcher Servlet's init-param:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>myenv</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Or per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>profileName</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't do it for me. Since the value of spring.profiles.active is per war AND per env. I can't hardcode the spring profiles in web.xml. And i don't think there's a way to specify a dynamic property inside web.xml.