# Is there a way to have if/else conditions in an xml in spring mvc3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a properties file defined in my xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/db.properties"></property>    
</bean>
```

I have a property in the file:

```
someprop = one
```

**Question**

In my XML I would like to either add/remove a property in a bean definition. For example:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.internal.url}" />
    <!--I want to add/remove the line below based on value in property file-->
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.internal.username}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Might I suggest having different property files for different environments instead. That is the "standard" way to solve this.

Comment: that could work as well. Though, I'm confused as to how it'll be determined which one gets picked up? Do I have to configure an environment name in tomcat? Is there a link that goes in depth?

Comment: Anyway, since this is XML and not properties file. I'll still have to change the xml file when deploying from one env to the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be possible using SpringEL. Read the **Expression support for defining bean definitions** section [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html).

If this is to handle multiple environments then Spring 3.1 provides [bean definition profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) and [Environment](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) abstractions.

Comment: I haven't found this answer in the links you suggested. How does the profile get trigger? Say I have two profiles, where do I make one of them active

Comment: @birdy the active profile can be set multiple ways. See this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v