# spring profile groups

Tags: java, spring, profiles, spring-profiles

I have an application, for which I can specify the profiles I want to run it on.
but I also want to group these profiles into things like credentails, application performance, memory-print, application behaviour etc.
Ex. I can run the following profiles

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=production,cached-local,db-connection-pooled...
```

but I would prefer initializing it as

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=production,super-fast
#the above activates method level caches, db connection pooling etc
#super-fast triggered activation of cached-local, db-connection-pooled profiles
```

or

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,low-footprint
#the above dosent enable caching, or db connection pooling
```

can this be achieved without writing any custom code like 
[How to set active spring 3.1 environment profile via a properites file and not via an env variable or system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v).
I am fine even if I can load these from properties files or inside spring-xml config.
I am using xml only config on spring 3.1.

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? I'm trying to come up with a solution to do something similar.

Comment: sorry for delay. No i havent found solution for this. let me know if you did.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot have since added functionality to address this problem, called "Profile Groups". A profile group allows you to define a logical name for a related group of profiles.

For example, we can create a `production` group that consists of our `proddb` and `prodmq` profiles.

This allows for a grouping to be defined, which is added to the spring-profiles-active, which when enabled, in turn, enables other profiles.

For more information see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles.groups

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to achieve this without custom code which would manipulate the active profiles in a `ConfigurableEnvironment`.

We're trying to achieve the same indirection pattern as rights vs. roles (group of rights) in a security framework, but since this doesn't come out of the box, I ended up having to work around it.

I kept my profiles general, e.g. production and super-fast in your case, and for each bean that is sensitive to those profiles, I set the correct @Profile. To make refactoring easier, I used two techniques.

1. Create a meta-annotation for each profile, e.g. `@Production`, `@SuperFast` and make the profile name a public constant, e.g. `Production.PROFILE_NAME = "production"`.
2. When marking the profile of any bean, use your new meta-annotation if it only applies to one profile, or use `@Profile({Production.PROFILE_NAME, ...})` if it applies to multiple profiles. You have to do this because you can't apply two profile meta-annotations to the same bean, [at least not until 4.0](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10812).

For example,

```
@Profile(Production.PROFILE_NAME)
public @interface Production {

    public static String PROFILE_NAME = "production";
}
```

The point of all this is that you can now use your IDE to look for usages of `@Production` or `Production.PROFILE_NAME` if you need to quickly understand or change what beans are being pulled in.