# Enable a Spring profile depending on other profiles unavailablilty

Tags: java, spring

I want to create 2 spring profiles , one runs in test and others in other environments. Depending on a profile that is inactive , i need to define some beans. So essentially want to do below

e.g.

```
<beans profile="test">
<bean id="testconstructorBean" 
....
</beans>
<!- is test is not available-->
<beans profile="!test">
<bean id="constructorBean"
...
</beans>
```

I have seen on reference [spring profles group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731979/spring-profile-groups), which can also work. But what i want is to have 2 alternative configurations which cannot coexists.

Regards
N

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand, you can use `profile="!test"` right, that is a valid construct, are you having issues in using this construct?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) and set the `spring.profiles.active` programmatically based on your conditions.

[This article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles) discusses ways to set profiles based on environments, which sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: But the declaration only defines active profiles and does not activates any grouping/disabled profiles.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. But with the way I suggested, you should be able to active either profile (or both if you wanted to, but it doesn't sound like you). If you only active one, the other will be disabled. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to handle cases where we have profiles like DEV/SIT/UAT/PROD and another as TEST. I want some beans to be only active if TEST profile is provided, regardless if other profiles are active or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: But in that case i have to make sure that I activate those profiles. `code`<beans profile="test">
<bean id="testconstructorBean" 
....
</beans>
<!- is test is not available-->
<beans profile="DEV,SIT,UAT,PROD">
<bean id="constructorBean"
...
</beans>`code`  , but my actual intent if to create a bean with different configuration for TEST and NONTEST environment.

Comment: Correct, you need different active profiles for each one. You can put the beans in different files, and then each profile will load one of those bean files.