# Optional @PropertySource location

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I'm using Spring 3.2 in a web application and I'd like to have a `.properties` file within the classpath which contains default values. The user should be able to use JNDI to define a location where another `.properties` is stored which overrides the default values.

The following works as long as the user has set the `configLocation` as JNDI property.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:default.properties", "file:${java:comp/env/configLocation}/override.properties" })
public class AppConfig
{
}
```

However, the external overrides should be optional and so should the JNDI property.

Currently I get an exception (`java.io.FileNotFoundException: comp\env\configLocation\app.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)` when the JNDI property is missing.

How can I define optional `.properties` that are used only when the JNDI property (`configLocation`) is set? Is this even possible with `@PropertySource` or is there another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. Create a `ApplicationContextInitializer`

In a Web Context: `ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext>` and register it in the web.xml via:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>...ContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In the ContextInitializer you can add your property files via classpath and file system (haven't tried JNDI though).

```
  public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    String activeProfileName = null;
    String location = null;

    try {
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
      String appconfigDir = environment.getProperty(APPCONFIG);
      if (appconfigDir == null ) {
        logger.error("missing property: " + APPCONFIG);
        appconfigDir = "/tmp";
      }
      String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();

      for ( int i = 0; i < activeProfiles.length; i++ ) {
        activeProfileName = activeProfiles[i];
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
        location = "file://" + appconfigDir + activeProfileName + ".properties";
        addPropertySource(applicationContext, activeProfileName,
                location, propertySources);
        location = "classpath:/" + activeProfileName + ".properties";
        addPropertySource(applicationContext, activeProfileName,
                          location, propertySources);
      }
      logger.debug("environment: '{}'", environment.getProperty("env"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.info("could not find properties file for active Spring profile '{}' (tried '{}')", activeProfileName, location);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void addPropertySource(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext, String activeProfileName,
                                 String location, MutablePropertySources propertySources) throws IOException {
    Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(location);
    if ( resource.exists() ) {
      ResourcePropertySource propertySource = new ResourcePropertySource(location);
      propertySources.addLast(propertySource);
    } else {
      logger.info("could not find properties file for active Spring profile '{}' (tried '{}')", activeProfileName, location);
    }
  }
```

The code above tries to find a property file per active profile (see: [How to set active spring 3.1 environment profile via a properites file and not via an env variable or system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v))

Comment: Thanks. I've also solved it using an `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Looks like it's the only feasible way to do it.

Answer (score 52):

As of Spring 4, issue [SPR-8371](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8371) has been solved. Consequently, the `@PropertySource` annotation has a new attribute called `ignoreResourceNotFound` that has been added for exactly this purpose. Additionally, there is also the new [@PropertySources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html) annotation which allows implementations like:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:default.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:/path_to_file/optional_override.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
```

Comment: Note as per `@PropertySources` JavaDoc, in Java 8, you can directly apply multiple `@PropertySource` annotations to a class without the wrapper.

Comment: @billc.cn Quite right. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/16/spring-propertysource/) about a year ago about `@PropertySource` in which I also mentioned [Java 8's repeating annotations](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/120).

Answer (score 5):

If you're not yet on Spring 4 (see matsev's solution), here's a more verbose, but roughly equivalent solution:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void addOptionalProperties(StandardEnvironment environment) {
        try {
            String localPropertiesPath = environment.resolvePlaceholders("file:${java:comp/env/configLocation}/override.properties");
            ResourcePropertySource localPropertySource = new ResourcePropertySource(localPropertiesPath);
            environment.getPropertySources().addLast(localPropertySource);
        } catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }

}
```