# Java Based Configuration and factory pattern

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern

Suppose I've a class `Fruit` and it's two subclasses - `Apple` and `Grape`:

```
class Fruit {
    public void grind() { }
}

class Apple extends Fruit { }
class Grape extends Fruit { }
```

In spring properties file, I've a property that decides which bean to register at startup. At a time, I'll only have either `Apple` or `Grape` instance registered as a bean. The property is:

```
# This can be either apple or grape
app.fruit = apple
```

In the Java configuration file, I'm binding a `String` attribute using `@Value` with this property, and based on that, I'll create appropriate instance. I'm trying to use factory pattern here. So, I've a `FruitFactory` like this:

```
class FruitFactory {
    private Map<String, Fruit> map = new HashMap<String, Fruit>();

    public FruitFactory() {
        map.put("apple", new Apple());
        map.put("grape", new Grape());
    }

    public Fruit getFruit(String fruit) {
        return map.get(fruit);
    }
}
```

And here's my spring configuration class:

```
class SpringConfig {
    @Value("${app.fruit}")
    private String fruitType;

    @Bean
    public FruitFactory fruitFactory() {
        return new FruitFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public Fruit getFruit() {
          return fruitFactory().getFruit(fruitType);
    }
}
```

So, here're my few questions:

- Will the instances stored in the map inside the factory be spring managed bean? Is there any issue with the implementation? I've tried it, and it is working fine, and I'm confused whether the instances are really spring managed.
- I was trying to implement it in a better way, so that when a new fruit comes, I don't have to modify my factory. On way is to provide a `register()` method in factory and let all the `Fruit` subclasses invoke it. But the issue is when and how the subclasses will be loaded? I'll not be using the classes, not before putting their instances into the map. Can anyone suggest a better way?

---

**Edit:**

As suggested in comment and answer, I've tried using `@Profile` instead of factory pattern. But I'm facing some issues in that. Here's what I've:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("apple")
class AppleProfile {
    @Bean
    public Fruit getApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("grape")
class GrapeProfile {
    @Bean
    public Fruit getGrape() {
        return new Grape();
    }
}
```

And in a `ServletListener`, I've set the active profile:

```
class MyServletListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Value("${app.fruit}")
    private String fruitType;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
        // Get Spring Context
        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(contextEvent
            .getServletContext());
        context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);

        ConfigurableEnvironment configEnvironment = (ConfigurableEnvironment) context.getEnvironment();
        logger.debug("0;Setting Active Profile: " + cacheRetrievalMode);

        configEnvironment.setActiveProfiles(cacheRetrievalMode);
    }
}
```

This is properly setting the active profile, which I can see. The only issue is, the listener is declared before the `ContextLoaderListener`, and by the time this is executed, the beans are already been created. Is there any alternative?

Comment: If you really want `Apple` and `Grape` to be managed, I would drop the factory, annotate `Apple` and `Grape` with `@Component` and [`@Profile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) and use the active profile to dictate what a fruit is, this way any new fruit can be added by adding annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the instances stored in the map inside the factory be spring
>   managed bean?

Making the `FruitFactory` a managed bean

```
@Bean
public FruitFactory fruitFactory() {
    return new FruitFactory();
}
```

doesn't make any of the objects it's referring to managed beans. However, this

```
@Bean
public Fruit getFruit() {
      return fruitFactory().getFruit(fruitType);
}
```

does make that one returned `Fruit` a managed bean. `@Bean` marks a method as a bean definition and bean factory (it creates the bean). The object you return will be managed by Spring's bean life cycle.

> Is there any issue with the implementation?

It seems weird that you're creating a `FruitFactory` bean but also a `Fruit` from that same `FruitFactory`. Are you even going to inject the `FruitFactory` elsewhere in the application?

> I was trying to implement it in a better way, so that when a new fruit
>   comes, I don't have to modify my factory

Seriously, your factory is messing everything up. Spring already does its job, and more! Annotations make your life easier. You can give an identifier to the `@Bean`. You can qualify the bean with `@Qualifier` (and then also qualify the injection target with `@Qualifier`). You can set a `@Profile` for when and under which conditions the bean should be initialized.

> But the issue is when and how the subclasses will be loaded? I'll not
>   be using the classes, not before putting their instances into the map.
>   Can anyone suggest a better way?

You can use bean `initMethod`s, which you specify as a `@Bean` annotation attribute, or a `@PostConstruct` annotated method to do post-initialization logic. You can use these to register the beans with the factory, which you'll have injected (but that design doesn't sound right to me, you'd have to show us more.)

You should also look into `InitializingBean` and `FactoryBean`.

---

For setting the active profile, one possibility is to do the following. Create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which sets the active profile by reading from a `.properties` file. You won't be able to use `@PropertySources` here because this isn't a bean.

Something like

```
public class ProfileContextInitializer implements
        ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        PropertySource<Map<String, Object>> source = null;
        try {
            source = new ResourcePropertySource("spring.properties");
            String profile = (String) source.getProperty("active.profile");
            System.out.println(profile);
            ConfigurableEnvironment env = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
            env.setActiveProfiles(profile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can register this in your deployment descriptor

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.yourapp.ProfileContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

When the `ContextLoaderListener` is created, it will pick up and instantiate your class and call its `initialize` method. This is done before the `WebApplicationContext` is refreshed.

You should probably just set a VM argument for the active profile and avoid all of this.

Comment: No I'm not going to inject `FruitFactory` anywhere. I just used it to register a particular bean. Didn't knew it is not a prefered way. Oh, and yes, never heard of `@Profile`. It seems to be the thing which I need here. But where I would register the profile? I thought to do it in a `ServletContextListener`, but will I be able to read property file there? No, I guess :(

Comment: Also, to use the `@Qualifier` I would have to register both `Apple` and `Grape` as spring bean, which I don't want to do. Or are you telling to use it along with `@Profile`?

Comment: @RohitJain active profiles are setup with a system property or an environment variable or ... (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v)). The property is replaced by the profile name, so no need to read it

Comment: @Sotirios I've updated my question. Can you take a look?

Comment: @Sotirios Is there any way I can read properties from spring configuration file, before all the beans are initialized?

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, I went to bed. You can cast your `WebApplicationContext` to a `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` and call `refresh`. This will refresh all the beans and use the new active profile. I'm putting an alternative as an edit.

Comment: @RohitJain Actually, are you deploying with web.xml or with `WebApplicationInitializer`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using `web.xml`, where we've registered the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So, in the Listener, which comes after the `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml`, if I do a `refresh()`, it will re-initialize the spring context? Is it that way? If it is, then my work is done. But I can only try this tomorrow, when I reach office.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And what would you suggest personally? `ApplicationContextInitializer` which was the last thing which I did before leaving office, and it worked, or `Listener`? What I didn't like about the `ApplicationContextInitializer` approach is I've to load the property file again there, while we've a different `PropertiesConfiguration` file where we're registering the `PropertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer`.