# Production vs staging - adding staging specific controllers

Tags: java, spring, svn, production-environment, staging

We are using spring with a tomcat 7 cluster for our web application.

In order to do an load testing our staging server we need to have some sort of a "special controller".
This controller is providing some really risky operations that must not reach the production server!

What is the best way to do this? how can we create this code, add it to our svn, and still make it unavailable to production deployment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [Spring profile](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/). You can set a bean to load only when a specific profile is active. This way this controller would load only when profile `staging` is active.

For example you can define:

```
@Controller
@Profile("staging")
public class SpecialController { 
  ...
}
```

You need to pass in the `JVM` options the profile `-Dactive.profiles=staging`

Answer (score 1):

Spring has special feature for this named "profiles". You can define `staging` profile, create as many beans as you need marked for this profile. Then, when you are running application you just have to supply JVM option `-Dspring.profiles.active=staging` and all staging targeted beans will run. Otherwise they will be ignored.

Comment: Is it possible to configure the active profile not via the JVM options? for example via a xml?

Comment: @Urbanleg, you can also configure active profile using web.xml's `context-param`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v