# Personalized ApplicationContextInitializer can be the cause of Error Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]?

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, weblogic

I am getting an error that the application I am deploying can not find the /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml.

This is my web.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sheidaei.chnlsales.web.util.P13nApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this is the customized class:

```
package com.sheidaei.chnlsales.web.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class P13nApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    protected static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(P13nApplicationContextInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        try {                   
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:env.properties"));
            //environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:root-context.xml"));
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml"));
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:fw-refresh-spring.xml"));
            LOG.info("env.properties loaded");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // it's ok if the file is not there. we will just log that info.
            LOG.info("didn't find env.properties in classpath so not loading it in the AppContextInitialized");
        }
    }

}
```

I was trying to create a personalized ApplicationContextInitializer based on the discussion here: [How to set active spring 3.1 environment profile via a properites file and not via an env variable or system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v) but I wasn't successful.

Prior to changing to the customized class my web.xml looked like the following (and the application could be deployed successfully)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>          
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, 
        classpath:fw-refresh-spring.xml
    </param-value> 
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
-->
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationContextInitializer` can be used to configure profiles and property sources (`.properties` files), but not Spring configuration files (`.xml` files).

Remote the following lines:

```
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml"));
environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:fw-refresh-spring.xml"));
```

and return `contextConfigLocation` to `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>          
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, 
        classpath:fw-refresh-spring.xml
    </param-value> 
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks @axtavt. Could I have more than one <context-param> in web.xml then?

Comment: Yes, as long as they have different `<param-name>`s