# Inject spring beans based on a System Property

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

My project framework is designed in such a way that I don't have access to Springs ApplicationContext. However, I would like to inject beans based on a system property. If the property is set to true, then inject all the beans, else inject none. Is this a possibility. Something like the below. BTW, Spring version is 3.0

```
    <!-- all beans -->
      <bean></bean>
      <bean></bean>
      <bean></bean>
      <bean class ="org.springframework...PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer>
        <property name = "properties"
          <value>
            OBJECT_INSTANCE_ID =0
          </value>
        </property>
     <bean>
```

In short the property is read using PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. All other beans should load based on value OBJECT_INSTANCE_ID. The property is defined in a property file located at /etc/../system.property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Spring profiles to achieve this functionality:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="devConfig" class="<yourClassName>" />
</beans>
```

In the above example, the `devConfig` bean will be constructed only if `dev` profile is activated. You can activate a profile as follows:

**Using annotations:**

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
```

**Using system property:**

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Profiles can still be used for your scenario. You can find different ways to set profile here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v

Answer (score 0):

If you would go for modern approaches like Java configs and Spring Boot, you can use [@ConditionalOnProperty annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-property-conditions) that Spring Boot introduced as one of the conditional injections.