# Conditionally including beans in XML ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, spring

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow conditionally include spring beans depending on some property.

In my `applicationContext.xml` I have a list of beans that I setup:

```
<bean id="server1Config" class="... />
<bean id="server2Config" class="... />
<bean id="server3Config" class="... />
...
```

Then I include them in a list:

```
<bean class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="server1Config"/>
                <ref bean="server2Config"/>
                <ref bean="server3Config"/>
                ...
            </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I want to conditionally include server1Config, server2Config, server3Config, etc depending on whether `${includeServer1} == true`, `${includeServer2} == true` etc and if possible, only initialize those beans if they are marked for inclusion.

To clarify, it's a ping service checking if servers are online or not, each bean contains special urls. If I have 5 servers running, I'd like to set in my config `includeServer1=true` ... `includeServer5=true` ... `includeServer6=false`, if I shutdown server2, I'd like to change includeServer2=false before shutting down the server to not get bombarded with SMSe telling me server2 is offline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your names refer to different stages or enviroments, spring profiles might be helpful to use. You can define beans like this inside your context.xml

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/datasource"/>
</beans>
```

In the example [1] you see the usage of two profiles called "dev" and "production".

- Spring will always load every bean without a profile
- Depending on the profiles (yes, you can load multiple profiles at once) all the related beans will be loaded

Loading a profile in Java:

```
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
```

Loading two profiles

```
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("profile1", "profile2");
```

Loading from CMD Line declaratively:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="profile1,profile2"
```

Usage in web.xml (can be comma-separated)

```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
          <param-value>production</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

@Comment: If you want to do it using properties and you are able to use newer spring elements, annotations etc. please have a look at this tutorial [2] to make it work with properties file as you commented below.

[1] http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/
[2] http://kielczewski.eu/2013/11/setting-active-profile-and-property-sources-in-spring-mvc/

Comment: I'm compiling to a war file and the server I'm deploying to only has a Tomcat Admin panel, so no command line access. Is there a way to set the profile in XML via a properties file? Something like <context:env profiles="${profiles}" />

Comment: Updated regarding your question

Comment: Is web.xml the only way to set spring profiles ? 
Still a potential solution if I can exclude things from the list using profiles, how would I exclude items from the ArrayList, or will they automatically be excluded if their beans doesn't match the profile?

Comment: As far as I know only for spring boot is a mechanism available where you can place the property inside the application.properties and it will automatically be loaded (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) But as far as I can see you don't use this. If you use spring in a web application, the context is loaded by spring based on the web.xml - do you see any obstacles with this solution for your application?

Comment: The only place I currently need to update config is in application.properties which I include via `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>`, so was hoping for a solution where I can commit applicationContext.xml, never touch it again and only modify myapp.properties

Comment: Here is another solution if you work with annotations or consider to switch to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587489/how-to-set-active-spring-3-1-environment-profile-via-a-properites-file-and-not-v

Answer (score 4):

This is  almost an add-on to @swinkler's answer.

He gave the first part of the solution which is usage of Spring 3.1+ profiles.

The second part would be to use a kind of automatic registration :

```
<bean class="java.util.ArrayList" id="serverConfigList"/>
<beans profile="server1">
    <bean id="server1Config" class="... />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject"><ref local="serverConfigList"/></property>
        <property name="targetMethod"><value>add</value></property>
        <property name="arguments"><ref local="server1Config/></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

That way you create an empy list and only add relevant configs to it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code shouldn't change based on environment. If your aim is to use different settings for each environment then load them as properties at start up.

Refer this for '[external configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)'

Comment: Not using Spring Boot, but will keep it in mind if I use Spring Boot in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Spring framework 3.1 onwards using a built in Spring environment profiles.

Here's a few resources: 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles

Hope this helps.

Comment: Spring Profiles is a potential solution now that I found out I can load multiple profiles. I can see how I would exclude beans from being initialized, will that automatically exclude them from the list or will they be inserted as null into the list if their profile doesn't match?