# Loading environment properties using Spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties-file, spring-profiles

I am working in `Spring, Java, Ant` web application. I am using Spring profiling to load properties based on the enironment. Below is the sample

```
@Profile("dev")
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:dev.properties")
public class DevPropertiesConfig{

}
@Profile("qa")
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:qa.properties")
public class TestPropertiesConfig {

}

@Profile("live")
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:live.properties")
public class LivePropertiesConfig{

}
```

In **web.xml**, we can give the profile

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Now, my query is for every environment i need to create a separate Java class.

**Question:** Is it possible to have only one class like providing profile name as some binding parameter like `@Profile({profile})`.

Also, let me know if there is other better option available to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes it is possible, and you have done it right.

Comment: Instead of this use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which based on the active profiles add a `ResourcePropertySource` pointing to the file for that profile. That is also what Spring Boot (more or less) does.

Comment: For detailed example of @M.Deinum answer, refer this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8601353/3898076).

Comment: I have deleted my solution, as it was hard coding profile names. You can refer solution in above SO answer link.

Comment: @M.Deinum, is it possible to create single bean for loading the properties files. As OP has to use 3 separate classes.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple profiles active at one time, so there is no single property to obtain the active profile. A general solution is to create an `ApplicationContextInitializer` which based on the active profiles loads additional configuration files.

```
public class ProfileConfigurationInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = ctg.getEnvironment();
        String[] profiles = env.getActiveProfiles();
        if (!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(profiles)) {
            MutablePropertySources mps = env.getPropertySources();
            for (String profile : profiles) {
               Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(profile+".properties");
               if (resource.exists() ) {
                   mps.addLast(profile + "-properties", new ResourcePropertySource(resource);
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick (might contain errors as I typed it from the top of my head).

Now in your `web.xml` include a context parameter named `contextInitializerClasses` and give it the name of your initializer.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>your.package.ProfileConfigurationInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>
```