# Profile-specific Properties Files WITHOUT spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

We know spring boot supports *Profile-specific Properties Files* , meaning we can has one `app.properties` defining common/shared key-value pair and additional `app-[prod|dev|stage].properties`. With `spring.profiles.active` , we can switch different profile .

But I wonder if this is available in normal spring context WITHOUT spring-boot ?

The most important requirement : I don't want to hard-code profile in any Java/XML/Kotlin code (except in Tests , which may assign `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` ). Which means

This is not ideal :

```
@PropertySources(
  PropertySource(value = ["classpath:app.properties"]),
  PropertySource(value = ["classpath:app-dev.properties"], ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
)
```

as it hard-coded `dev` in the code.

And this is not acceptable

```
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer().apply {
  setLocations(
    ClassPathResource("app.properties") ,
    ClassPathResource("app-dev.properties")
  )
}
```

as it also hard-coded `dev` in the code.

Solution like :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

is not acceptable , as there will be an `app-.properties` storing common/shared K/V , which is very ugly (the redundant `-` character )

XML solutions are welcome , but such as

```
app-prod.xml
<beans profile="prod">
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties,classpath:app-prod.properties" />
</beans>
and
app-dev.xml
<beans profile="dev">
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties,classpath:app-dev.properties" />
</beans>
```

is not so good. As it is not auto-discovery.

I hope it can auto discover relevant profiles , for example : `app.properties` , `app-prod.properties` , `app-dev.properties` and automatically knows there are two profiles (`prod` and `dev`). With `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` , it automatically picks up `app.properties` and `app-dev.properties`, and uses `dev` to override default KVs. Just like what spring-boot does. But without boot environment.

This will be packed in WAR and deployed to Tomcat. So , no spring boot needed.

Environment : spring-core 5.3.13

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue, a legacy Spring Framework project where I needed the Spring Boot sort of functionality - this solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268713/1697482