# Setting the environment/profile in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I have a Spring 4 MVC app in which I'd like to pass in the environment (profile) from the command line and have it read the correct environment-specific `.properties` files on startup.

These properties files essentially contain different `jdbc` connection strings so each environment can connect to the correct database.

I'm still learning Spring and Java in general, so having a hard time figuring this out.

In `web.xml` I define 3 environments/profiles

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
  <param-value>test, dev, prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have 3 environment specific files under resources directory. My understanding is that Spring will try to source the appropriate environment specific file and a generic `application.properties` file (if one exists, and it doesn't here) to fall back on.

```
> \ls src/main/webapp/resources/properties/
application-dev.properties  application-prod.properties application-test.properties
```

Each file is pretty simple, just jdbc connection params for that environment. Example:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/galapagos
jdbc.username=foo
jdbc.password=
```

Lastly in my servlet file `spring-web-servlet.xml`, I read the application properties file and use it to establish a connection

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

  ....

  <!-- Database / JDBC -->

  <beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="location" value="resources/properties/application.properties" />
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </beans:bean>

  ....

</beans:beans>
```

This is erroring out, because it's trying to look for a `resources/properties/application.properties` which doesn't exist. But I'm not sure what else to put in there. How do I get it to dynamically read the correct environment's file on startup?

I saw some examples [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601353/2490003) using context listeners, but honestly I'm still learning Spring MVC and don't really understand what those are trying to do

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, spring will to try to find `resources/properties/application.properties` to load properties. This file is auto-detected.
This is your problem and you have to provide one. If you don't like to have an application.properties file, you can override it names by specifing `spring.config.name` environment property and its location by using `spring.config.location` environment property.

In your `web.xml`,

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
 <param-value>test, dev, prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You are activating 3 profiles at the same time. I would suggest to define which profile is activated in your `application.properties`. For example :

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Then, the specific environnment file will be loaded and will take precedence over the default property file.

Comment: **Spring** won't look for application.properties by default, it is **Spring Boot** which will do so, please don't mislead others

Answer (score 0):

You may pass through the command prompt while building.
eg: mvn clean package -Pdev

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).